# How to test Spring service beans that themself have autowired dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I'd like to test some services that them themself contain other autowired services. But these "external" services are not required for the test itself.

How can I create a test setup, eg for the following example?

```
package de.myapp.service;

@Service
public class MyServiceDelegator {
    @Autowired
    private List<ServiceInterface> services;

    public ServiceInterface delegate(String id) {
        //routine to find the right ServiceInterface based on the given id
    }
}


@Service
public class MyService implements ServiceInterface {

}

@Service
public class MyCustomService implements ServiceInterface {
    //that is the problem during testing
    @Autowired
    private de.myapp.repository.SomeDao dao;
}


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("applicationContext.xml")
public class ServiceDelegatorTest {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ac

    @Test
    public void testDelegator() {
        MyServiceDelegator dg = ac.getBean(MyServiceDelegator.class);
        ac.delegate("test");
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan  base-package="de.myapp.service" />
</beans>
```

Problem: All services that contain autowired dependencies from packages that are not scanned within the `JUnit` test (like `MyCustomService`), will throw an Exception:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [SomeDao] found for dependency: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this
>   dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
>     ... 57 more

Comment: Are you using the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`?

Comment: yes, see `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` above

Comment: Ah, sorry, the classes ran together and I missed it.

Comment: The usual approach is to create an `application-text.xml` that defines the extra beans you need for testing. Is this not feasible for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) to add mocked service implementations to your test application context.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mockito="http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
                       http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito
                       http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito.xsd">

    <context:component-scan  base-package="de.myapp.service" />

    <mockito:mock id="dao" class="de.myapp.repository.SomeDao" />

</beans>
```

Comment: That's a perfect framework! Is it also possible to mock `@Value` annotations with it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `SomeDao` is not being picked up by component scanning because it's not under the `de.myapp.service` package.

You have explicitly stated that the package for component scanning is `de.myapp.service`.

I sugggest you make the following change:

`<context:component-scan  base-package="de.myapp" />`

That way all the code under `de.myapp` will be eligible for component scanning.

If you want to avoid including all your code in component scanning you could do the following:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="de.myapp.service, de.myapp.repository" />
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid extending the package scanning, because `SomeDao` itself will then contain another injected dependency that has another depencendy that has another dependency, that may have a bean that is only available in a webserver application context (like a  `ContextCloseListener` or similar). I don't think scanning my whole application is a good solution for testing just a single requirement...

Comment: Yes, thanks, but the problem remains, as the repository bean is also only an example here: any beans may contain any further beans that are outside of the current scanned context. So I'd have to add the all spring services, which makes it difficult as some of them will be webserver dependent, database configuration etc.

Comment: I see your point. But if you want actual integration tests, you have to include the dependency beans somehow. That will either be done using component scanning, XML or Java Config (possibly along with Spring Profiles)